# is it possible to stop php sessions carrying over from different folders

Tags: php, session

I have a file structure like and I use `$_SESSION['userID']` to track who is logged in:

```
Main Index (a hub for all my websites)
|
|--/_lm/index.html (website 2)
|
|--/_da/index.html (website 3)
|
|--/_vm/index.html (website 4)
```

I have found that once someone logs into, for example, `website 2` - their `$_SESSION['userID']` will carry over to the other websites.

What would be the best way to top this from happening? Is there a way to *confine* session data to a certain folder?

Comment: session never transfer or work on different website, each website has its own unique session

Comment: @Sourabh, I think you are misunderstanding...

Comment: If those are *truly* different sites, they should be set up as such via virtual hosts (assuming Apache), in which case PHP will handle sessions correctly for you. If you want them to continue to exist as folders within a single site, you'll have to specify different array keys for each user ID (e.g. `$_SESSION['userID_lm']`, `$_SESSION['userID_da']`, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use $_SESSION['userID'] to validate every session. once you set this it works across the site.

So try this

website 1 session

```
$_SESSION['userID1']
```

website 2 session

```
$_SESSION['userID2']
```

website 3 session

```
$_SESSION['userID3']
```

website 4 session

```
$_SESSION['userID4']
```

Comment: I suppose that would be the best way of fixing the issue, i was just hoping to be able to use the same variable.